# how to check tcp peer is closed

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP network connection with remote host.(windows or linux)
if remote host process is terminated, recv() fails
an I know the connection is closed.

but, is there any way to check if the remote host
has closed connection without actually receiving data?

the point is, I want to periodically check if the remote host is still alive
but I don't want to give or receive any data.

thank you in advance

Comment: There's no way to check if the remote host is alive, if you don't want to give or recv data.

Comment: I think you want to use TCP Keep-Alive (Using `SO_KEEPALIVE`)

Comment: @Hasturkun That still requires you to do some I/O, otherwise you will never find out.

Comment: @EJP: Not exactly. There's no additional data _in the stream_. Obviously zero length packets are sent.

Comment: @EJP: Oh, wait. I understand what you're saying. He'll still need to call `recv()` or `select()` or similar at some point to detect the connection being closed. I still think keepalive is the right thing here.

Comment: @Hasturkun It will help, slightly, with the cut cable problem, after two hours, but it doesn't answer the question of how to do it without sending or receiving data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear, `recv()` should not fail if the connection has been closed properly. It should return EOF (0 bytes). `recv()` will fail is the connection was closed abnormally.

To check if the connection has been closed without actually receiving data if it hasn't been, the best you can probably do is call `recvmsg()` with the `MSG_PEEK` flag. Ask for just one byte. If the connection has been closed then you'll get EOF (normal close) or an error (abnormal close). If it hasn't been closed, you'll either get `EAGAIN` (assuming you put the socket in non-blocking mode) or one byte of data. So, yes, technically you received a byte of data, but because of `MSG_PEEK` the kernel doesn't record the fact that you did, so it's as if you didn't. This all assumes that you've already read out of the kernel's buffer all of the data from the stream that arrived before the prospective error might have happened.

Of course [rakib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2231815/rakib)'s comment applies: "There's no way to check if the remote host is alive, if you don't want to give or recv data.". Meaning this method won't detect scenarios like the remote host disappearing off the network without closing the connection, etc...

Comment: Asking for just one byte probably isn't enough, as system can buffer up to 0.5MB so reading just 1 byte from it would look like client did not close connection. Maybe peeking for 1MB would detect it.

Comment: @sheerun good point. I should have said this would allow you to detect the condition once you had caught up in the stream buffer to the point where the prospective error would have happened.

Answer (score 1):

If you are monitoring the socket's ready-for-read state via select(), select() will return and indicate that the socket has data ready to read.  Then when you try to recv() that data, recv() will either fail (if there was an error) or return 0 (to indicate EOF if the connection was closed cleanly).